# Props declared as interface not available when navigating to a Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have Component wherein props are declared as an interface and that component takes in the type as that interface.

For eg ->

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'


 interface IDummy{
    name:string;
    age:number;
}
export default class Dummy extends Component<IDummy,any> {
    constructor(props:IDummy){
        super(props)
        console.log('CHeck the props here ',props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> Just Text </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Now if I use that component as a part of other components such as

```
<Text>Something</Text>
<Dummy/>
```

The props name and age work fine.
But when I want to navigate to that component,

```
navigation.navigate('Dummy')
```

the props mentioned in the interface are not available.
Is there any way I could access them ???

Comment: npm install -D @types/react-navigation

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose you are using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)

in order to send parameters, you should navigate using following line:

```
navigation.navigate('Dummy', {
  name: 'name',
  age: 'age',
});
```

once you navigation event have been dispatched, you could read values like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'


interface IDummy{
  name: string;
  age: number;
  route: any;
}

export default class Dummy extends Component<IDummy,any> {

    constructor(props: IDummy){
        super(props)
        console.log('properties from navigation ', props.route.params);
        console.log('Check the props here ',props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> Just Text </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

More about it: [Passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params)